# Why is my hmac key off?

Tags: go

I am trying to generate an hmac key for use in an image proxy. I have:

https://play.golang.org/p/fec_N2Nim4

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("secret key"))
        mac.Write([]byte("https://octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg"))
        want := mac.Sum(nil)
        fmt.Println("result: ",base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(want)) // expect "sXyMwWKIC5JPCtlYOQ2f4yMBTqpjtUsfI67Sp7huXIYY="
}
```

This is based off [the package's](https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy#signed-requests) recommended formula for generating the key as well as other methods I have tried, which all result in the same key. The url given in the example, however, has an "s" prepended to the front:

http://localhost:8080/500,sXyMwWKIC5JPCtlYOQ2f4yMBTqpjtUsfI67Sp7huXIYY=/https://octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg

vs what I am getting:

```
http://localhost:8080/500,XyMwWKIC5JPCtlYOQ2f4yMBTqpjtUsfI67Sp7huXIYY=/https://octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg
```

Comment: every key for each url I've passed in needs to similarly prepended with "s"

Comment: I tried you example..it also generates the same key. I dont see any problem here. Why do you want to prepend "s" to it?

Comment: The example url given is "http://localhost:8080/500,sXyMwWKIC5JPCtlYOQ2f4yMBTqpjtUsfI67Sp7huXIYY=/https://octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg"...notice the "s" they prepend to it. My key doesn't have the "s"

Comment: I think they might have some format to prepend 's' to the actual key.

Comment: Just found on there docs page please check https://godoc.org/willnorris.com/go/imageproxy#hdr-Signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs of the given library, the key format is as below:

```
s{signature}
```

Please check the docs at [Url signing signature](https://godoc.org/willnorris.com/go/imageproxy#hdr-Signature)